# Overseas FBI Fingerprinting

Tags: paperwork

In order to get an FBI Identity History Summary, you need to be fingerprinted. If traveling to the States isn't an option, what ways are there in order to get the correct type of fingerprinting done overseas? Preference for places such as Tunisia or Turkey, but anything in Europe would work as well. Assume the person is not a US citizen, and cannot use a channeller.

Not sure where to ask this question, but as it is overseas I posted it in Travel.

Comment: Why do you need your FBI Identity History and how is it related to Travel?

Comment: @JonathanReez For example, if applying for Canadian residency and state that you have previously lived in the us, they require a identity history summary, regardless of your status in the us.